# How to make previous image go below an expanded image

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, containers

I have a webpage with 16 images on it. Each image takes up 49.7% of the container width. So essentially I have 2 columns and 8 rows. I wrote some jQuery code that expands the image you click on to 99.5% width as to take up 2 columns.

This works great, but when I click an image on the second column, It is placed below the image on the first column. I don't want that to happen, I want the image to be on top of the image on the first column. Hopefully that makes sense. I will provide my code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('imgwidth');
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 49.7%;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 3px;
  top: 100px;
}
.imgwidth {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/8x1" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/8x1" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/8x1" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/8x1" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/8x1" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/8x1" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/8x1" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/8x1" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/8x1" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/8x1" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/8x1" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/8x1" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/8x1" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/8x1" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/8x1" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/8x1" />
  </div>
</main>
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Lfcfr97o/)**

Answer (score 0):

Well. This is not complete but it's gonna give you a starting point and show that this actually ain't easy.

First check the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/abzqs9um/2/) please.

In JS code i used a `moved` data attr to define whether it's a moved item or not. For your desire, we're gonna move the items on 2nd column before the previous item. Further explanations are gonna be inside the code as comments.

```
$('img').on('click', function() {
  var ind = $(this).index();
  if ($(this).data("moved")) {
    // check if this is moved. If it is that means it was pushed back
    // before previous item so we're gonna move it after again
    $(this).data("moved",false).insertAfter($(this).next("img"));
  } else if (ind % 2 == 1 && !$(this).prev("img").hasClass("imgwidth") && !$(this).hasClass("imgwidth")) {
    // check if the item is on 2nd column by % calculation
    // if it is and previous item isn't expanded and it is also not expanded yet
    // this means we're gonna put this one before previous one
    $(this).data("moved",true).insertBefore($(this).prev("img"));
  } else if (ind % 2 == 1 && $(this).prev("img").data("moved") && !$(this).hasClass("imgwidth")) {
    // if it's on the 2nd column and previous one has data moved and
    // this one is not expanded yet
    // that means this one was actually before in the first place so
    // we're gonna put it back and remove data on the next one
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev("img"));
    $(this).prev("img").data("moved", false)
  } else if (ind % 2 == 0 && $(this).next("img").has("imgwidth") && $(this).hasClass("imgwidth")) {
    // if it's on the 1st column and next img is expanded and
    // this one is also expanded, next one needs to be pushed before this
    // and have data true
    $(this).insertAfter($(this).next("img"));
    $(this).prev("img").data("moved", true)
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('imgwidth');
});
```

It may have some fails but like I said it's a starting point.

Comment: Yeah, I tried something similar to what you suggested but I can't get it perfect. Thanks for your input even though your code is also flawed. I guess I will keep trying unless someone comes through with an easier way.